# JsonObject gives typeMisMatch error

Tags: android, json

I am getting a JSON.typeMisMatch error on line 3 below in my android app.  I don't understand why because I am able to access this array in other programs.

```
         1   JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
         2   Log.d("jsonObj=", String.valueOf(jsonObj));
         3   JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("obit"); // This is the error line
         4   JSONObject jsonObit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

            obituary = jsonObit.getString(("Obit"));
```

Below is a console display of line 2:

```
        D/jsonObj=﹕ {"obit":{"Obit":"John R. Uphoff, 94, of Heritage Manor of Minonk, died at 1:18 a.m. Thursday ...
```

And here is the error I get:

```
         org.json.JSONException: Value {"Obit":"John R. Uphoff, 94, of Heritage Manor of Minonk, died
```

I have accessed this json string in other programs but get an error in this situation.  Does anyone know why this error occurrs?

Comment: obit is not an array it's an object

Answer (score 1):

That is another JSONObject,

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("obit");
```

Replace it with,

```
JSONObject jsonOuterObit = jsonObj.getJSONObject("obit");
```

and then get a string,

```
obituary = jsonOuterObit.getString(("Obit"));
```

Comment: Stack overflow comes through again!  Thanks for the advice.  Works great now.  Still don't understand why this string is different from the string in the other program but then I am a newbie to Android.

Comment: Just remember two things, {} - means JSONObject and [] - means JSONArray and parse accordingly to your json.

Comment: OK.  Thanks for the information.  That is definitely worth knowing.